# Using a checkbox to 'enable' another checkbox & display a hidden textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, checkbox

I am very new to programming, basically attempting to self learn since Feb.  I have managed to create a basic form using Visual Studio/MVC5 but I am struggling with some of the more complicated functionally.

Here I have a disabled checkbox (id=withdrawn) and I want it to become enabled once I tick the 'update' (id=update) checkbox.  I also want the 'RefNumber' textbox to only display, once this same 'update' checkbox is ticked.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
@model F10New.ViewModels.NewSubmissionForm
@{
ViewBag.Title = "NewSubmission";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Notifications"))

{

<p>*Is this the initial notification of the project p>

<div class="form-inline">
<div class="checkbox" id="initialNotification">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Intial, new { @enabled   = "enabled" }) Initial notification        </label>
</div>    
<div class="checkbox" id="update">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Update) Update to an existing notification
    </label>
</div>
```

```
    <div class="checkbox" id="withdrawn">                       
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Withdrawn, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) The project has been withdrawn
        </label>
    </div>    

<b>Details of the locations(s) of the site</b>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.MultiSite) Check this box if this project has multiple site locations
    </label>
</div>

<p>What is the exact address ?</p>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.Address1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Address1, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "(eg building name, address, location, grid ref)" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.Address1)

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.Address2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Address2, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "(eg street number, street name)" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.Address2)

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.Address3)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Address3, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "(eg district)" })

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.Town)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Town, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.Town)

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.County)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.County, new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" id="postCodeField">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.PostCode)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.PostCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.PostCode)

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addressSearch">Search for Address</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group" id="submissionDropdown">

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.CountryId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Notification.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "Name"), "Please choose one", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.CountryId)
        </div>


        <div class="form-group" id="submissionDropdown">


            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.AreaId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Notification.AreaId, new SelectList(Model.Areas, "Id", "Name"), "Select Country first", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.AreaId)

        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="submissionDropdown">


            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.LocalId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Notification.LocalId, new SelectList(Model.Locals, "Id", "Name"), "Select a Geographical Area first", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.LocalId)

        </div>
    </div>


    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Notification.Id)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="pageOneSubmit">Submit</button>
}
@section scripts
{
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Notification_Update").on('change', function(){
     $("#Notification_Withdrawn").removeAttr("disabled");       
      $("#Notification_Initial").removeAttr("enabled");
  });
})
</script>


}
```

Comment: Where is your JS code?

Comment: {@disabled = "disbaled" } - disbaled is a typo

Answer (score 0):

include jquery then

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Notification_Update").on('change', function(){
         $("#Notification_Withdrawn").removeAttr("disabled");
         $("#my_hidden_input_id").show();

      });
  });
</script>
```

Update

Add custom id to HTML control using HTML helper.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Withdrawn, 
   new { @disabled = "disabled", @id="Withdrawn" }) 

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Update, 
   new { @id="Update" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have added this code to the bottom of my view but nothing happens when I tick the update checkbox (I know I will be missing something but as mentioned, I am very new to this).  I have included my full page of code this time in case it helps & corrected the disabled typo (thanks to Gerard).

Comment: You are almost there. your ids update and withdraw are ids for div which contain checkbox but in HTML DOM you get Update and Withdraw as your checkbox id so change that thing.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Bhuban, but not sure what you mean? Thanks again

Comment: I mean to say replace update with Update and withdraw with Withdraw.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was what you meant so did try it but get same result:

@section scripts
{
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Update").on('change', function(){
         $("#Withdrawn").removeAttr("disabled");       

      });
})
</script>

}

Comment: In browser inspect your checkbox and look at its id what you get in ID field there. If Id you get in browser doesn't equal to ID in script section then replace ID of script section with ID you get in browser.
You may get Notification.Update in browser so in script section replace Update with Notification.Update

Comment: That was it!  I needed to change to #Notification_Update & #Notification_Withdrawn in order for to work.  Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: I already have, it says it is recorded but not displayed as I have a reputation of less than 15. Thanks again

Comment: Could I trouble you again?  I have updated my code (above) as I also want the initialNotification checkbox to disable on the same click.  I have tried a few variations without any luck/

Comment: Add $(this).attr("disabled","disabled") on change event